# How to set the scroll position in a LazyHStack in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview

I have a horizontally scrolling LazyHStack. How do I set the initial scroll position?

In UIKit, I would create a horizontally scrolling UICollectionView and set the `collectionView.contentOffset` to set the initial scroll position, but I'm not sure how to do this in SwiftUI.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            LazyHStack {
                ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { i in             
                    Text("\(i)")
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ScrollViewReader`

### Manual scroll

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { value in
            Button("Go to #15") {
                value.scrollTo(15, anchor: .center)
            }
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                LazyHStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) {
                        Text("Column \($0)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Automatic scroll

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { value in
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                LazyHStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) {
                        Text("Column \($0)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                value.scrollTo(15, anchor: .center)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for this great answer. One thing. Will it work with custom struct/class?

Comment: @AlexanderKhitev for sure but you need to know SwiftUI's views are structs